# Show contacts in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using this code to display contacts in lisview. It is working fine except for one thing. It's showing all the contacts including email id and other contacts.

I want to show those contacts who for whoever has phone numbers. How I can do that?

Here is my code:-

```
    public class PhoneBookActivity extends Activity {

        //Android listview object
        ListView listViewPhoneBook;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.phone_book);

          //get the ListView Reference from xml file
          listViewPhoneBook=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPhoneBook);

          //arrayColumns is the array which will contain all contacts name in your cursor, where the cursor will get the data from contacts database.
          //Here we are displaying name only from the contacts database
          String[] arrayColumns = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
          //arrayViewID is the id of the view it will map to here textViewName only , you can add more Views as per Requirement
          int[] arrayViewID = new int[]{R.id.textViewName};

         //reference to the phone contacts database using  Cursor and URI in android. 
          Cursor cursor;
         cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        /*Create an Adapter with arguments layoutID, Cursor, Array Of Columns, and Array of Views which is to be Populated
        This adapter will be associated with the listview to populate items directly. So this adapter is associated with 
        the each_contact.xlm file to view in a activity */
         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.each_contact, cursor, arrayColumns, arrayViewID);
         listViewPhoneBook.setAdapter(adapter);

         /*this is extra code for click event of any item in the list view.
         when you will click on na contact's name in the list view. it will give you the item name and position in a listview.
         Note that: if you want to query the contacts name details(like phone number for the clicked contact name  & all details,
         we need to query it again. i will explain it in my a separate post in my blog.*/

         // To handle the click on List View Item
         listViewPhoneBook.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
             {
                 // position parameter gives the index or position of ListView Item which is Clicked
                 TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                 String name=tv.getText().toString();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Selected: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        });

        }
    }
```

UPDATE:---

I solved one of my problem myself. 
Now i have another issue. 
How can i get phone number on phone contact click in this list view?

I am trying to do this:

```
   // To handle the click on List View Item
            listViewPhoneBook.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
                {
                    // position parameter gives the index or position of ListView Item which is Clicked
                    TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                    String name=tv.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Selected: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   // Cursor c = (Cursor)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Selected: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });
```

Error:-
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)

Comment: Please add more information about the android's version you want your application to run on, it may help to clarify the classes you can use.

Comment: this code is working on android 4.2, so i want to run my code on android 4.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, we need to add selection in cursor.

```
 String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Kotlin:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var cr = contentResolver
    var c=cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null)
    var from = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
    var to =   intArrayOf(R.id.name,R.id.number)
    var adapter=SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.indiview,c,from,to,0)
    lview.adapter = adapter

     lview?.onItemClickListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            var phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            var list= mutableListOf<String>()
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                var name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                var phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                list.add(phoneNumber)
            }
           var i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,list.get(p2),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            i.data = Uri.parse("tel:${list.get(p2)}")
            startActivity(i)

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.